# Request parameters showing as undefined

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose

I'm trying to pass some URL params from a react component to a database query in a separate file. Here's a breakdown of what I'm trying to do:

TL;DR: the api request doesn't seem to have the category and city fields defined when I try to query the database.

1) Grab search params from a search form component

```
<Link to={"tours"+"/" + this.state.category + "/" + this.state.city} >
```

2) User clicks search, gets redirected to search results component. Once they are redirected, this function gets called. As I expect, the props are printing with the params from the search form.

```
componentDidMount: function() {

// console.log(this.props.route);

console.log(this.props.params.category);
console.log(this.props.params.city);

var category = this.props.params.category;
var city = this.props.params.city;

helpers.viewTours(
{
  cat: category,
  cit: city
}
).then(function(response){
    var tours = response.data.length ? response.data[0].tour_title : 0;
    console.log("RESPONSE " + response);
    console.log("RESPONSE LENGTH " + response.data.length);
    console.log("RESULTS ", tours);
    //this.setState({trekList: response});
})
```

},

3) Using a wrapper function (helpers.viewTours) I want to pass those params from the search form into a database query

```
  viewTours: function(searchParams){

console.log("search params " + searchParams);
return axios.get("/tours/search", searchParams);
```

},

4) This method gets called, but the params are undefined

```
  router.get("/search", function(req, res){
  var category = req.body.cat;
  var city = req.body.cit;
  console.log("tours cat " + category);
  console.log("tours cit " + city);
  Tour.find({}, function(error, doc) {
    // Send any errors to the browser
    if (error) {
      res.send(error);
    }
    // Or send the doc to the browser
    else {
      res.send(doc);
      //return doc;
    }
  });

});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Could you show what logs out for each of your console.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `axios` documentation, `axios.get(url, [config])` where config can be to send data with request, e.g. `params` field or `data` field. `data` field is not valid for `GET` request.

You can try the following to send params to backend.

```
viewTours: function(searchParams){
   console.log("search params " + searchParams);
   return axios.get("/tours/search", { params: searchParams });
},
```

and on server side, use `req.params` to fetch params from url.

```
router.get("/search", function(req, res){
   var category = req.params.cat;
   var city = req.params.city;
   // rest of code
})
```

Comment: That did it! I realized i was also using body within the req, but that wont work since it's a GET request.